# SELECT, get the invert result from the WHERE on the JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, join, where-clause, inverse

I have this MySQL request to get all the shops having an invoice on a specific date:

```
SELECT sh__shop.id AS shop_id, sh__shop.name,
       sh__shop_invoice.*
FROM sh__shop 
LEFT JOIN sh__shop_invoice ON sh__shop_invoice.shop_id = sh__shop.id
WHERE sh__shop_invoice.month_commission LIKE "2021-08-01"
```

But I can't see how to get the inverse. All the shops not having an invoice on the specific date. I can't do `NOT LIKE "2021-08-01"`.

Comment: Why can't you do `NOT LIKE`? And because your LIKE doesn't contain any wildcards why not just do a basic comparison `=`?

Comment: Why can't you do NOT LIKE? However, I'd use `<>` instead.

Comment: Also, move sh__shop_invoice from WHERE to ON to get true LEFT JOIN result. As it is now, you get regular INNER JOIN result.

Comment: Presumably you don't mean all the shops without an invoice, but all the shops with an invoice that's not that date. Why are you using `like` for an equality?

Comment: Do not use `LIKE` for dates!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make it by using `not exists`.

```
SELECT sh__shop.id AS shop_id, sh__shop.name
FROM sh__shop 
WHERE 
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sh__shop_invoice i
            WHERE i.shop_id = sh__shop.id
                  AND i.month_commission LIKE "2021-08-01");
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try using left join but for nkt matching  rows

```
SELECT distnct sh__shop.id AS shop_id
FROM sh__shop 
LEFT JOIN sh__shop_invoice ON sh__shop_invoice.shop_id = sh__shop.id
    AND  sh__shop_invoice.month_commission LIKE "2021-08-01"
WHERE sh__shop_invoice.shop_id is null
```

(In your query you are using left join in wrong way because adding  the left joined  column  in where clause this work as an inner join)